# Dynamically change a button-drop list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, drop-down-menu

Trying to create a changeable button-drop-down from Bootstrap HTML in conjunction with Javascript. The HTML looks as:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Menu
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Choice..</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Would like to be able to change the choices of the drop-down button based on what else is happening on the page. So if user clicks a "profile" button somewhere on the page instead of Choice1, Choice2 and Choice3 there would be Resume, Contact Info, Education etc. The number of items in the menu would change as would the exact values for the display text. Ideally would like to use some type of array to push/pop from the choices. Have tried add, childappend, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach - have all your menu items in the HTML, and then use CSS to hide/show the appropriate ones

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Menu
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul id='my-dropdown' class="dropdown-menu" data-menu-id='default'>
       <li class='default'><a href="#">Choice1</a></li>
       <li class='default'><a href="#">Choice2</a></li>
       <li class='default'><a href="#">Choice3</a></li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li class='default'><a href="#">Choice..</a></li>
       <li class='profile'><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
       <li class='profile'><a href="#">Education</a></li>
       <li class='badgers'><a href="#">Eat a badger</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* hide all menu items */
ul.dropdown-menu > li {
    display: none; 
}

/* show menu items if they're relevant */
ul.dropdown-menu[data-menu-id=default] > li.default, 
ul.dropdown-menu[data-menu-id=profile] > li.profile, 
ul.dropdown-menu[data-menu-id=badgers] > li.badgers {
   display: list-item;
}
```

Now use javascript to change the `data-menu-id` attribute on your dropdown, and the menu items will change automatically:

```
var dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('my-dropdown');
dropdownMenu.setAttribute("data-menu-id", "profile");
```

Lots of other ways to do this, but this is probably the slickest approach. The CSS basically says "if the class of the list item matches the menu id attribute on the parent, make it visible".

An advantage of this approach is that you can make a menu item visible in multiple different menus just by giving it multiple classes:

```
<!-- will be visible in the 'profile' menu and the 'badger' one -->
<li class='profile badgers'><a href="#">Badger Resume</a></li>
```